# Time the execution of batch file commands of VB scripts without using WScript.sleep

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, automation

I have a batch file which starts telnet server and stops telnet server with sleep time in between.

**Script:**

```
set OBJECT=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.sleep 5000
OBJECT.SendKeys "net stop TlntSvr{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 30000
OBJECT.SendKeys "net start TlntSvr{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 30000
OBJECT.SendKeys "exit"
```

Like you see the above code stops *telnet services* using `net stop TlntSvr` and then starts telnet services using `net start TlntSvr` with a sleep time in between like `WScript.sleep 3000`.

**Issue:**
Now I need to run **this batch file** in multiple systems PCs/laptop and in each execution cases, the time taken to start/stop *telnet services/telnet service installation* varies and hence I had to **modify the sleep time every time** when I am running the script in different systems.

**Question:**
Is there a way to time the next execution such that as soon as the first execution completes only then it will start the next execution? Meaning I don't need to configure the sleep time for each laptops/PCS, the next execution will start only when the first execution is over according to each PC's own execution behavior.

Comment: What if the vbscript outputs a flag file and the bat loops until it sees that file?

Comment: I am not understanding what you are doing.  Batch files are sequential processing.  The next command does not execute until the previous command completes.

Comment: Sqaushman - I am performing FTP and UDP automation using VBscript. Of so many vbscripts and batch files, there are certain commands (like above) are being executed sequentially. Now if the sleep time between two sequential commands are not timed, one might overlap the other. So I want to time the sequential execution such that the next command will start only when the previous command ends without using `WScript.sleep <time>`

Comment: Why is everyone so hell-bent on scripting a non-scriptable telnet via `SendKeys` instead of simply using a [telnet that actually *is* scriptable](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)?

Comment: squashman - made a easier question for, I have removed all the complications. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing aren't ***batch file commands***.  If you want batch to do this then the below is equivalent:

```
Net Stop TlnSvr
PING -n 31 127.0.0.1>nul
Net Start TlnSvr
PING -n 31 127.0.0.1>nul
```

However, batch commands are sequential and if all you need is for the each command to finish before moving on, then you can just remove the Ping delays.

```
Net Stop TlnSvr
Net Start TlnSvr
```

We still use some Batch files in part because we have to have many different commands run sequentially and ensure that one is done before the next kicks off.

If I've missed the boat, please comment and I'll edit this.

**Edit:**  Following up after comments.

In VBscript you can catch the date/time at the time the first command executes then monitor the date/time between commands to ensure the correct timing.

```
Dim TimeDif:  TimeDif = 40 'seconds
Dim CmdTime:  CmdTime = now()
'... do your first command here...
do while datediff("S", CmdTime, now()) < TimeDif
    wscript.sleep(5000) '5 seconds
loop
'... do your second command here...
```

Now the timer is taking into account the command execution time, not just sleeping a static time between commands.

Set the TimeDif to be the Command Start to next Command Start difference in seconds.

**Edit:**  This one is more graceful.  No loop.  It calculates the time difference and sleeps that time.

```
Dim TimeDif:  TimeDif = 30 'seconds
Dim CmdTime:  CmdTime = now()
Dim ToNext
'... do your first command here...
ToNext = (TimeDif * datediff("S", CmdTime, now())) * 1000
wscript.sleep(ToNext)
'... do your second command here...
```

Comment: The problem I am facing is something else. Say for **any such batch commands** each command execution takes different time in each workstations. Say **command 1** takes **24 secs** to execute in **system A**, while the same command takes **1 min** to execute in **system B** because of system speed/performance. So instead of configuring the sleep time again and again according to need, the script will itself decide when to start the next command. Can it be done programmatically?

Comment: Not independently if what you are trying to do is sync the execution of every system so they run at the same time (what I think i'm reading).  If the times that it has to run are long enough apart, then you can probably get close by using a trigger file (semaphore) that everyone looks for.  I'll edit my post to show something like that.

Comment: No I don't want to sync the execution but I want the script to decide itself when to start the second command when the first one is over. Say the command is **net stop TlnSvr** **sleep 40 secs** **net start TlnSvr** but the command takes 5 secs in **system A** only to execute but since sleep time is 40 I had to wait for extra 35 secs which is a waste of time.

Comment: OK, let me think about timing in a batch file.  I'll post something.

Comment: Alternatively if the command is **net stop TlnSvr | sleep 40 secs | net start TlnSvr** but the command takes 80 secs to execute in another system but since sleep time is already set to 40 seconds my second command never executes. So again I had to **add 40 secs** to the script for **system B** else my script will fail. So just think if I had to do this for 100 systems I am gone case, history!

Comment: There is no easy way to do timing like this in a batch file because the date/time handling is so limited.  You can do it in a VB script which it looks like you are open to.  In vbscript i'd capture the time when the first command kicked off then watch the time difference and launch the second command at whatever the time spec is for not running it before x time.  If your machine is really slow that may mean not much wait time between.  Does that sound like what you are looking for?

Comment: I had to execute this batch file by going to each system and running it. So that means I need to configure the sleep time for each systems, will your tweaks in the script solve that? I am talking about 100 laptops/PCs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99668/discussion-between-rlh-and-arka-b).